# Not able to create client for web service in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jbossws

`I am using JBossWS as runtime environment and server configuration as JBoss AS 4.2
As I click on Finish button for creating client , I get teh following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/wsf/spi/tools/cmd/WSConsume 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.wsf.spi.tools.cmd.WSConsume 
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) 
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) 
Could not find the main class: org.jboss.wsf.spi.tools.cmd.WSConsume.  Program will   exit. 
Exception in thread "main"
```

`

Comment: I get exactly the same for JBoss AS 7 when I use the ANT task. Didn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score -1):

Add `jbossws-spi.jar` JAR to your CLASSPATH. This file can be found JBoss's `/jars` directory.

Comment: I added jbossws-spi.jar from Project build path. But could not get my problem solved. Please suggest some other way if possible.